# django, update modified_at when doing update()

Tags: python, django

Following field gets updated whenever model_obj.save() happens.

```
   modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

However, it is not updated when doing `MyModel.objects.filter(id=model_obj.id).update(**kwargs)`

Is there a way to somehow enforce updating `modified_at`?

Answer (score 2):

`auto_now` only updated when you call `save()` after `update` statement.

From Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField)

> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.
>
> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.